# Django Queryset slice makes many queries to the database

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Have an view code:

```
posts = category.category_posts.filter(
    ~Q(pk=id),
    date_published__lte=timezone.now(),
    is_active=True).order_by('-date_published')[:19]

right_now = posts[:5]
actual    = posts[5:10]
old_1     = posts[10:12]
old_2     = posts[12:14]
old_3     = posts[14:19]
```

When rendering in the template, Django performs a query to the database for each slice. Just 5. A Queryset is lazy. As to reduce to a one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate the queryset first by converting it to a list before before slicing it again.

```
posts = list(posts)
right_now = ...
```